# Store hyperlinks to a dynamic range from powerpoint?

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink, powerpoint

So I have a large powerpoint presentation which I'm using the following code to modify part of all of the hyperlinks within the presentation (to remove part of the file path to use relative rather than absolute referencing):

```
Dim oSl As Slide
Dim oHl As Hyperlink
Dim sSearchFor As String
Dim sReplaceWith As String
Dim oSh As Shape

sSearchFor = InputBox("What text should I search for?", "Search for ...")
If sSearchFor = "" Then
    Exit Sub
End If

sReplaceWith = InputBox("What text should I replace" & vbCrLf _
    & sSearchFor & vbCrLf _
    & "with?", "Replace with ...")
'If sReplaceWith = "" Then
'    Exit Sub
'End If

On Error Resume Next

For Each oSl In ActivePresentation.Slides

    For Each oHl In oSl.Hyperlinks
        oHl.Address = Replace(oHl.Address, sSearchFor, sReplaceWith)
        oHl.SubAddress = Replace(oHl.SubAddress, sSearchFor, sReplaceWith)
    Next    ' hyperlink

    For Each oSh In oSl.Shapes
       If oSh.Type = msoLinkedOLEObject _
        Or oSh.Type = msoMedia Then
          oSh.LinkFormat.SourceFullName = _
               Replace(oSh.LinkFormat.SourceFullName, _
               sSearchFor, sReplaceWith)
       End If
   Next

Next    ' slide
```

What I want to do to QA this is to display the original hyperlinks and the modified hyperlinks side by side in an excel sheet to compare original and new links to make sure that everything is working OK.

My first post here, I tried google but not much joy, any help much appreciated!!

Thanks

James

Answer (score 1):

Something like this can works, but you will need to add the Microsoft Excel reference

```
Dim oSl As Slide
Dim oHl As Hyperlink
Dim sSearchFor As String
Dim sReplaceWith As String
Dim oSh As Shape
Dim wk As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim i As Double

Set wk = Workbooks.Add
Set ws = wk.Worksheets(1)

ws.Cells(1, 1).Value = "original"
ws.Cells(1, 2).Value = "modified"
i = 2

sSearchFor = InputBox("What text should I search for?", "Search for ...")
If sSearchFor = "" Then
    Exit Sub
End If

sReplaceWith = InputBox("What text should I replace" & vbCrLf _
    & sSearchFor & vbCrLf _
    & "with?", "Replace with ...")
'If sReplaceWith = "" Then
'    Exit Sub
'End If

On Error Resume Next

For Each oSl In ActivePresentation.Slides

    For Each oHl In oSl.Hyperlinks
        ws.Cells(i, 1).Value = oH1.Address 'original
        oHl.Address = Replace(oHl.Address, sSearchFor, sReplaceWith) 'modification
        ws.Cells(i, 2).Value = oH1.Address 'modified
        i = i + 1
        oHl.SubAddress = Replace(oHl.SubAddress, sSearchFor, sReplaceWith)
    Next    ' hyperlink

    For Each oSh In oSl.Shapes
       If oSh.Type = msoLinkedOLEObject _
        Or oSh.Type = msoMedia Then
          oSh.LinkFormat.SourceFullName = _
               Replace(oSh.LinkFormat.SourceFullName, _
               sSearchFor, sReplaceWith)
       End If
   Next

Next    ' slide
```